# Best way to append object in JSON file?

Tags: c#, json, wpf, json.net

I have a JSON file with `Person` objects and I can't find a comfortable way to append more objects.
Example:
`[
  {"name": "x", "id": "001"}
]`
I tried with List<> and serialize/deserialize but it doesn't seems to work.
**Edit:**
This happens after clicking a button:

```
Person person = new Person();
person.fName = name.Text;
person.id = int.Parse(id.Text);

string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "\\Project\\";

using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(path + "persons.json")) {
    string json = r.ReadToEnd();
    List<Person> persons = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Person>>(json);
    persons.Add(person);
    string newJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(persons);
    File.WriteAllText(path + "persons.json", newJson);
    r.Close();
}
```

Comment: Can you post what have you tried? The only option I see is to deserialize the file and after appending the object serialize it again

Comment: so, do you get any error? Do you get the deserialized object at all?

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin "The process cannot access the file _____ because it is being used by another process." This is the line with the bug: File.WriteAllText(path + "persons.json", newJson);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You get this error because you're trying to write into file which is open for reading.

To fix this your code needs to close the `StreamReader` first and then write to the file.

```
Person person = new Person();
person.fName = name.Text;
person.id = int.Parse(id.Text);

string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "\\Project\\";

using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(path + "persons.json")) {
    string json = r.ReadToEnd();
    List<Person> persons = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Person>>(json);
    persons.Add(person);
    string newJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(persons); 
} 

File.WriteAllText(path + "persons.json", newJson);
```

Alternatively, `File` class provides a shortcut for reading files and you code can look like this:

```
Person person = new Person();
person.fName = name.Text;
person.id = int.Parse(id.Text);

string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "\\Project\\";

string json = File.ReadAllText(path + "persons.json");
List<Person> persons = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Person>>(json);
persons.Add(person);
string newJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(persons);
File.WriteAllText(path + "persons.json", newJson);
```